# Sharepoint Site Not Showing in Azure Logic App Sharepoint Connector

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App which I use to connect to a couple of different SharePoint lists within the company I work for.  I have been granted access to another SharePoint list within the company (access confirmed using browser), but this new SharePoint list does not show up in my Logic App SharePoint connector.

All of the Azure resources mentioned are in the same domain.

What could be preventing this one SharePoint list from showing up in my connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it in my side, I can access to the site but also can't see the site in my logic app. But, since we have the access to the site, so we can just copy the link to the logic app. Please refer to the steps below:

1. Go to the site page in browser and copy the site link.
   [image]
2. Click "Enter custom value" and paste the link which we copied just now.
   [image]
3. Then we can select the file under this site.
   [image]